# Image has no method 'getContext'

Tags: node.js, canvas

I'm having problems and I guess it could be made from some missing library. I build a simple function that should be able to detect faces using https://github.com/orls/ccv-purejs

When I try to process a photo I have this error:

```
/home/admuser/foodstagram/node_modules/face-detect/lib/ccv.js:20
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                     ^
TypeError: Object #<Image> has no method 'getContext'
    at Object.module.exports.exports.grayscale (/home/admuser/foodstagram/node_m
odules/face-detect/lib/ccv.js:20:22)
    at Object.module.exports.exports.detect_objects (/home/admuser/foodstagram/n
ode_modules/face-detect/lib/ccv.js:108:27)
    at findFaces (/home/admuser/foodstagram/index.js:501:30)
    at null._onTimeout (/home/admuser/foodstagram/index.js:466:30)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Here is my code

```
var Image = require('canvas').Image;
function detectFace(){
  urlPhoto = "http://origincache-prn.fbcdn.net/10358219_569704703128581_477566036_a.jpg"
  request.get({ url: urlPhoto, encoding: null}, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var image = new Image();
    image.onerror = function() {
        console.error(arguments);
    };

    image.onload = function(){
      console.log('loaded image');
      findFaces(image);
    };

    image.src = new Buffer(body, 'base64');
  });
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a canvas element, then add the image to that canvas and pass the canvas to the library.

**FYI:**
This link if to create a canvas
https://www.npmjs.org/package/canvas

And this another is for add an image to the canvas 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Comment: I'm already creating a canvas object `var image = new Image();` and addind the image `image.src = new Buffer(body, 'base64');`

Comment: I mean something like this

`var Canvas = require('canvas');

image.onload = function(){
   var canvas = new Canvas(image.clientWidth, image.clientHeight), 
       ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(image,10,10);
   findFaces(canvas);
};`

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Error changed to `/home/admuser/foodstagram/node_modules/face-detect/lib/ccv.js:127
      var pyr = new Array((scale_upto + next * 2) * 4);
                ^
RangeError: Invalid array length`. Looking for solution.

Comment: It works! I had to fix the size of the canvas a bit bigger than the image. Don't know why but works.